# SQL Server : ExecuteReader doesn't throw error

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following code running, which should basically just execute a SQL statement against my database and if there is any error, the script should shout "ERROR!"

When I am running the script, with an invalid SQL statement in the `test.sql` file, the exception is correctly caught by the `CATCH` clause and "ERROR!" is written.

`Test.sql` file looks like this:

```
SELECT * FRRRROM [dbo].[testtable]
```

But, when I add a comment to the `test.sql` file, it doesn't throw the "ERROR!"-message anymore.

`Test.sql` file now looks like this:

```
-- my comment
SELECT * FRRRROM [dbo].[testtable]
```

I don't get it why. Any suggestions?

```
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='myServer';database='myDatabase';trusted_connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
$Connection.Open()

$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection 

$sql = Get-Content 'C:\Test\test.sql'

$Command.CommandText = $sql
Try
{
    $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
}
Catch 
{
    echo 'ERROR!!!!'
    Exit
}
$Connection.Close()
```

Comment: try `$sql = Get-Content 'C:\Test\test.sql' | Out-String` Do you get an error then? Difference in your second example `$sql` is an array and not just a newline delimited string.

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved the problem. Didn't knew that my example returned an array!
Thx again! you made my day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still would have expected an error but the main difference between your first and second example is you have another line. `Get-Content` returns a string *array*. With one line it would be just seen as a string. Easy way to be sure of that is to convert the text into one whole new line delimited string.

```
$sql = Get-Content 'C:\Test\test.sql' | Out-String
```

You could use -join or something else like that but I find `Out-String` is very simple and compatible with all versions of PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks again! 
additional question: Whats the best way to determine the error risen? reading the SQL Code of the execution. Sorry, i'm quite new into that topic

Comment: @EstebanP. Inside your catch you could look at `$error[0].Exception` which contains the exception message captured. Could be vague though. It depends on what `System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand` is willing to explain

Answer (score 0):

As user Matt mentioned:

The code returns an array to the variable `$sql`

```
$sql = Get-Content 'C:\Test\test.sql'
$Command.CommandText = $sql
```

after adding `| Out-String` it's working correctly, as returning a string

```
$Command.CommandText = Get-Content 'C:\Test\test.sql'| Out-String
```